# Cucumber Capybara scroll to bottom of page

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'd like to use my Cucumber/Capybara setup to test endless scroll by driving a browser and scrolling to the bottom of the page to ensure that the new content is loaded.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved this with `visit '#footer'` inside a "scroll to the bottom of the page" step.

Comment: This only works if you have an element with an `id` of `footer`. It also assumes (reasonably) that the footer is at the bottom of the page...

Comment: Genious. +1 even though not a direct answer ;))

Comment: @NatRitmeyer well yes... That's why it's called footer, yes?

Comment: Indeed :) But have you never seen a #footer that isn't at the bottom of the page?

Comment: more than discussing where the footer is placed, it assumes the footer _was loaded_! I got here looking for a way to take page screenshots of the bottom parts and, if there's some failure on the page, that method won't work :/ The JS solution is a bit safer in those cases.

Comment: This is good but it doesn't work for javascript SPAs that have `#` in the route. (sad face)

Answer (score 74):

You could use javascript to achieve this:

```
page.execute_script "window.scrollBy(0,10000)"
```

Comment: For Google purposes, I got here with the error "unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (750, 341). Other element would receive the click" and the solution was `page.execute_script "window.scrollBy(0,500)"`. Thanks!

Comment: If you have jQuery available you can run `window.scrollBy(0, $(window).height())`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my Angular app, I don't know why yet.

Comment: To be just as nitpicky as your comment on _visit '#footer'_, this only works if your page is less than 10000 units high.

Comment: @ArnaudMeuret I salute your pedantry :)

Answer (score 3):

A solution without jQuery or adapts to any height without magic numbers:

```rb
page.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
```

Answer (score 1):

As an example:

```rb
page.scroll_to(find('footer'))
```

More details [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement:scroll_to)

Comment: This should be the right answer in 2023.