# Auto scroll a button into view with Capybara and Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

Sometime last month (June 2013), several of our Capybara tests started failing mainly because the buttons they are trying to click are not in view. Ideally, I'd like to figure out what changed. We're currently on selenium-webdriver 2.33 but I've tried going back to 2.29 and it still doesn't work. We're running against Firefox only at the moment and maybe it's due to a newer version of Firefox.

Barring that, I can't figure out how to scroll the buttons into view. From what I gather, I can use scrollIntoView but not sure how to call it in the Capybara step. I tried variations on:

```
 Capybara.current_session.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true;)", find_button(button).native)
```

But with no luck because find_button itself doesn't work.

Note: we are selecting based on the button's text. Selecting based on ID is possible but will require a lot of changes to our UI tests so we'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Another note: the button is in a scrollable div. The page itself doesn't scroll.

Comment: What version of Firefox?  You might want to try uninstalling Firefox and then installing a specific version of Firefox and then disabling the upgrade on it so that it remains at the version you expect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I normally have a module `JavascriptDriver` that I use to include Selenium functionality in a test, and there I define a helper method:

```ruby
module JavascriptDriver
  # other code that prepares capybara to work with selenium

  def scroll_to(element)
    script = <<-JS
      arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);
    JS

    Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.execute_script(script, element.native)
  end
end
```

And then in your test you can utilize that code by passing a normal Capybara element:

```ruby
scroll_to(page.find("button.some-class", visible: false))
```

Comment: @CJohnson: Try with the `visible: false` option. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks man, you really saved my life! BTW, this also works for horizontal scroll :)

Comment: This works! BTW if the element is hidden under a static header like bootstrap header, it will not work. In my case I had to put `scrollBy(0, -50);` right after `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);`

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. You have no idea how much this just helped me and my team. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a scroll bug that has shown up in Selenium and Chrome. The fix is https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048669/1935918

Answer (score 1):

Since your page is not scrollable, you can use the same approach as the linked answer provided in the other answer, but with a variation to target your scrollable element. For example, if your scrollable element has an id of "scrollable":

```
page.execute_script "document.getElementById("scrollable").scrollTop += 100"
```

I personally hate having to scroll for tests, so if anyone comes up with a better solution to this for Capybara + Selenium, I'd love to see it.